# Find the equation of intersection of the planes in the form r*a=b

Tags: vectors

The plane 1 has vector equation r.(3i – 4j + 2k) = 5.
The plane 2 has vector equation r = m(2i + j + 5k) + n(i – j – 2k).
Find an equation of the lines of intersection of the two planes in the form r*a=b where a and b are constant vectors.

Comment: If "*" denotes a dot product, then the equation $r*a =b$ represents a plane, not a line.

Comment: It is probably r*a+b (r a scalar) and = was pressed by mistake.

Comment: Start for you: Write down the x, y and z coordinates of a point on plane 2 in terms of m and n. Substitute these into plane 1 (as the two planes are in the same place when they meet) and get an equation relating m and n.